# In Eclipse, how do I contribute a context/pop-up menu to a control in a dialog?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

Normally, in an Editor, one can contribute a context menu (declared in a org.eclipse.ui.menus extension) with something like the following.

```
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
Control menuParent = ... ;//some Control in the editor
Menu contextMenu = menuManager.createContextMenu(menuParent);
menuParent.setMenu(contextMenu);
getEditorSite().registerContextMenu(CONTEXT_MENU_ID, menuManager, getMySelectionProvider(), false);
```

I would like to do similar but in a Dialog.

Apparently, my Googling skills are lacking today because I can't seem to find anything but one person asking the same thing on DZone without success.

Is it even possible to contribute a menu via an extension point to a control in a Dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`IMenuService`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/menus/IMenuService.html) of workbench window:

```
IMenuService mSvc = (IMenuService) window.getService(IMenuService.class);
MenuManager mgr = new MenuManager();
mSvc.populateContributionManager(mgr, "popup:my.dialog.menu");
control.setMenu(mgr.createContextMenu(control));
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.  Now I just have to figure out some sort of handler enablement issue but that's unrelated, I believe.

Comment: @Jesse I don't know a way how you can provide selection to workbench without having a workbench part, so you probably won't be able to define enablement expressions based on current selection. Alternatively, you can use [contexts](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_contexts.htm).

Comment: +1: This was the only way for me to add a popup menu to an e4 part in a mixed e3/e4 application, when using the e4 bridge (i.e. DIViewPart). Instead of EMenuService you'd have to @Inject IMenuService.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did for a `ViewPart`.  I don't know if it will work for a `Dialog`.

```
protected void createContextMenu() {
    MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
    menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
    menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
        public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager m) {
            WorkAssignmentView.this.fillContextMenu(m);
        }
    });
    Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(activeViewer.getControl());
    activeViewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
    getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, activeViewer);
}
```

where `WorkAssignmentView` is the name of my `ViewPart` class, and `activeViewer` is a `TableViewer`.

If you can do the `control.getControl().setMenu(menu);`, then you should be able to use this as a model.

Here's the method that fills the context menu.

```
protected void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager menuMgr) {

    WorkAssignmentViewRow[] row = this.getSelectedAssignments();

    menuMgr.add(addAction);

        if (status.equals(WorkAssignmentViewRow.ACTIVE)) {
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(modifyAction);
            menuMgr.add(changeAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(deleteAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(whoIsModifyingAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(displayAction);
            menuMgr.add(displayFullAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(updateAction);
            menuMgr.add(commitAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(developmentMoveAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(testMoveAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(productionMoveAction);
            menuMgr.add(displayProductionAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
        } else if (status.equals(WorkAssignmentViewRow.INACTIVE)){
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(changeAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(deleteAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(displayAction);
            menuMgr.add(displayFullAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
        } else {
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
            menuMgr.add(displayAction);
            menuMgr.add(displayFullAction);
            menuMgr.add(new Separator());
        }

    menuMgr.add(new Separator(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I should have been more specific.  I have menu declared in a `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension that I am using in View already.  I would like to re-use it in a Dialog.  A dialog does not have a Site so I cannot call `registerContextMenu()`

Comment: As I said, I didn't know if this would work for a Dialog.  You're right that `registerContextMenu()` only works with editors and views.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to show context menu (which I also use in View) in custom table
control in Preferences dialog.

In my ViewPart I have method:

```
public static MyView getView() {
    MyView myView = (MyView) 
    Activator.getDefault().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().
    getActivePage().findView(MyView.ID);

    return myView;
}
```

In my RCP application the view is always visible, so the method should never
return null.

Then in ctor of my preference page, which opens in dialog:

```
    m_viewPart = MyView.getView();
```

And when creating a control in preference page, I register context menu with
my ViewPart:

```
    Control control = new ...
    MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
    Menu menu = menuManager.createContextMenu(control);
    control.setMenu(menu);
    viewPart.getSite().registerContextMenu("si.test.myCtxMenu", 
                                           menuManager, 
                                           selectionProvider);
```

Maybe it is not the best idea to register context menu of a component in dialog
to ViewPart, but it is simple and it works.